# How to change the data type from String into integer using pySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a *string* column (`yr_built`) of my csv file to Integer data type (`yr_builtInt`). I have tried to use the `cast()` method. But I am still getting an error:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

house5=house4.withColumn("yr_builtInt", col("yr_built").cast(IntegerType))
```

***Below is the output error I am getting***

```
TypeError: unexpected type: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last) <command-647635315551207> in <module>
----> 


1 house5=house4.withColumn("yr_builtInt", col("yr_built").cast(IntegerType))

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in cast(self, dataType)

    788             jc = self._jc.cast(jdt)
    789         else:
--> 790             raise TypeError("unexpected type: %s" % type(dataType))
    
    791         return Column(jc)
    792 

TypeError: unexpected type: <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataTypeSingleton'>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe it should be `IntegerType()` not `IntegerType`. See how it's done in [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.cast.html) with `StringType()` ...

Comment: or: `house5=house4.withColumn("yr_builtInt", col("yr_built").cast("int"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the following approaches:

Approach1 :

```
    house5=house4.withColumn("yr_builtInt", col("yr_built").cast(IntegerType()))
```

Approach2 :

```
    house5=house4.withColumn("yr_builtInt", col("yr_built").cast("int"))
```

Please check the sample code below:
[image]